# Reserve a space for an empty div css

Tags: html, css

I have a banner which is being loaded by AJAX in an empty div. This causes "Cumulative Layout Shift" problem which affects my website speed.

I tried to set both height and width for the div and insert a pace inside but that did not work

```
<div id='banner' width ='100%' height='425' style='min-height: 
425.3333435058594;clear:both;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to give the `min-height` value a unit... without one, it doesn't know what you mean.  And you **really** don't need to go to that level of precision.  Try `min-height:425px`

Comment: Pretty strange styling. Use external, not inline, don't need 100%, it's by default, no diff. between 425.3333435058594px and 425px, don't need &nbsp;... <div id='banner'></div> #banner {...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Height and width of a div should be set using css and min height should have an unit like `px`

```
<div id='banner' style= width: 100%; height: 425px; clear:both;'></div>
```